# Reducing the time of Update and Sum Query C# Access DB?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a simple query using query builder of VS2012 C# which updates the database in my winforms application. The database has 216 entries so far and it's taking a lifetime to update the database. How to reduce the time?
Should I make more queries for each column or is there something else? Here is the query:

```
UPDATE      StudentInfo
SET         PLO_1_Status = ?, PLO_2_Status = ?, PLO_3_Status=?,
            PLO_4_Status = ?, PLO_5_Status = ?, PLO_6_Status = ?, 
            PLO_7_Status = ?, PLO_8_Status = ?, PLO_9_Status = ?, 
            PLO_10_Status = ?, PLO_11_Status = ?, PLO_12_Status = ?
WHERE       (CMS_ID = ?)
```

And here is how I'm calling this query in C#. I am using QueryBuilder and DatasetDesigner and Access DB

```
for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
{
    this.studentInfoTableAdapter.UpdatePLO_Overall(
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO1[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO2[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO3[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO4[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO5[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO6[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO7[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO8[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO9[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO10[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO11[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO12[i]),
        CMS_ID_Var[i].ToString());
   this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
}
```

Comment: I understand CMS_ID_Var.Count = 216, so the UPDATE runs 216 times. Am I correct? Is there an Index CMS_ID?

Comment: Looking at your Code again, I see you run Fill on you DataSet, once for each of 216  Updates. instead of filling 216 rows to th DS, you fill 216^2 rows, that is 46656 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
{
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_1_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO1[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_2_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO2[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_3_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO3[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_4_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO4[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_5_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO5[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_6_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO6[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_7_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO7[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_8_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO8[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_9_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO9[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_10_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO10[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_11_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO11[i];
        this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo.rows[i].Item["PLO_12_Status"] = Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO12[i];
}
```

Make sour you have the correct Update Command in the Dataadapter, and update the entire table in one command. one trip to the DB:

```
this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Update(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
```

Comment: :) Thanks. You logic saved my bundles of time :)

Answer (score 1):

Fill the Dataset once, outside of the loop, after you update the table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CMS_ID_Var.Count; i++)
{
    this.studentInfoTableAdapter.UpdatePLO_Overall(
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO1[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO2[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO3[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO4[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO5[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO6[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO7[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO8[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO9[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO10[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO11[i]), 
        Convert.ToInt32(PercentageFormula_PLO12[i]),
        CMS_ID_Var[i].ToString());
}
this.studentInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.oBE_DB_1DataSet.StudentInfo);
```

Comment: i have tried this. and the timining remain miserable. no change in it.

Comment: @usamakhan, You have the client side do a lot of work on the *server side* **while in Access it is really the client retrieving the data, modifying it, and returning it to the DB**. I think you should first fill the dataTable, run the updates on this local copy (C#, not SQL), and have the DataAdapter Update command run the entire Datatable at once. Running 216 Update commands is bad practice.